# Missing math mode delimiter

Tags: math-mode

Please help, what's wrong with my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}   
\begin{center}    

$  
\begin{array}{lll}   
\text{Premis 1} & $ p \Rightarrow q $ &(Benar)\\   
\text{Premis 2} & $ p $ &(Benar) \\   
\text{Kesimpulan} & $\therefore q $ &(Benar)   
\end{array}   
$  

\end{center}   
\end{document}
```

Errors in line 11 and 13 saying that there are "missing $ inserted"

Comment: You have `$ ... $` within `array`. As you can see by the necessity to add `\text{}` around text within `array`, `array`'s cells will be in math mode, putting `$ ... $` in there takes you out of mathmode right before the maths and the puts you back in it right after the maths

Comment: Also you're using `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` around a text style equation, is there any reason you aren't displaying it with `\[ ... \]` or an `equation` environment

Comment: That's alright, there's also no need to load `amsfonts` if you load `amssymb` since `amssymb` itself loads `amsfonts`

Comment: Are you certain of that input encoding? Most editors default to unicode these days.